# ¿Cómo enviar un archivo adjunto a otro formulario?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy trabajando con HTML y JAVASCRIPT.

**FORMULARIO 1:** Usé la propiedad `<input="file">` para poder subir el archivo.

**FORMULARIO 2:** Es el que va a recibir ese archivo.

Envié datos así mismo `<input="text">` usando el siguiente código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url_string = window.location.href;//
var url = new URL(url_string);
var nombre = url.searchParams.get("nombre");
var contacto = url.searchParams.get("contacto");
var email = url.searchParams.get("email");
var pais = url.searchParams.get("pais");
var ciudad = url.searchParams.get("ciudad");
var fecha = url.searchParams.get("fecha");
var mensaje = url.searchParams.get("mensaje");


document.getElementById("nombre-obtenido").value=nombre;
document.getElementById("contacto-obtenido").value=contacto;
document.getElementById("email-obtenido").value=email;
document.getElementById("pais-obtenido").value=pais;
document.getElementById("ciudad-obtenida").value=ciudad;
document.getElementById("fecha-obtenido").value=fecha;
document.getElementById("mensaje-obtenido").value=mensaje;
</script>
```

Pero no sé cómo enviar el archivo adjunto, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Los formularios son para capturar datos no para recibirlos. ¿A que te refieres con que otro formulario va a recibirlos? Quizá con más info te pueda ayudar. ¿Qué tal si pones también tu código HTML.

Comment: Parece que el código que estás mostrando corresponde al segundo formulario. Los archivos no pueden enviarse por URL (método GET), debe ser por método POST y, además, el formulario debe contener la propiedad `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, de lo contrario no se enviará. Por último, no es posible manipular desde Javascript (navegador) los archivos agregados por el usuario, eso debe hacerse del lado del servidor.